# Css:Not able to remove inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to remove the following styles from an element but I can't figure out how.
It is  nor defined in my html/php:

```
<ul class="SliderBanner cf">
```

I have commented all of my css lines that have anything to do with this element and have already tried removing them with jQuery but no luck:

```
$('.SliderBanner.dots[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Any idea where this css is coming from?
Link to site: http://www.markomd22.twentytwo.axc.nl/ (down slider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an inline style. That's a class. Use that one:

```
$(".SliderBanner").removeClass( "SliderBanner cf" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not matching, the target element does not have the class `dots`

```
$('.SliderBanner.cf[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this,because it is a cssClass

**use** [**.removeClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
$(".SliderBanner").removeClass( "cf" );
$(".SliderBanner").removeClass( "SliderBanner" );
```

**OR**

```
$("ul").removeClass( "SliderBanner cf" );
```